# Error codes 80070490 and 8024200D in Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-update

How do get past these stupid errors?

The way I have set things up is that Windows Update tells me when there are new updates available and then I review them before installing them. Yesterday it told me that there were 11 new updates. So I reviewed them and I saw that about half of them were security updates for Vista x64 and .NET Framework 2.0 SP2, and half of them were just regular updates for Vista x64. I checked them all and hit the Install button. It seemed to work at first, updates were being downloaded and installed, but then at update 11 of 11 total it got stuck and gave me the two error codes you see in the title.

Here are some screenshots to give you an idea of what it looks like.

[image: windows update 1]

This is what it looks like when it presents the updates to me.

[image: windows update 2]

This is how it looks like when the installation fails.

[image: windows update 3]

I'm not sure if you're gonna see this very well but these are the updates it's trying to install.

Update:
[image: widnows update 4]

This is on Windows Vista Ultimate 64-bit with integrated SP2, installed only two weeks ago on 2012-10-02. Aside from this, the install is working flawlessly. I have not done any major changes to the system like installing new devices or drivers.

What I have tried so far:
- I tried installing the System Update Readiness Tool (the correct one for Vista x64) from Microsoft. This did not solve the issue.

**Microsoft resource links:**

*Solutions to 80070490*

[Windows Update error 80070490](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Windows-Update-error-80070490)

[System Update Readiness Tool fixes Windows Update errors in Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821)

*Solutions to 8024200D:*

[Windows Update error 8024200d](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Windows-Update-error-8024200d)

Essentially both solutions tell you to install the System Update Readiness Tool for your system. As I have done so and it didn't solve the problem the next step would be to try to repair Windows. Before I do that, is there anything else I can try?

**Microsoft automatic troubleshooter**

If I click the automatic troubleshooter link available on the solution web page above it directs me to download a file called `windowsupdate.diagcab`. But after download this file is not associated to any Windows program. Is this the so called Microsoft Fix It program? It doesn't have its icon, it's just blank file. Does it need to be associated? And to what Windows program?

[image: windows update 5]

**Some new screenshots:**
[image: windows update 6]

[image: windows update 7]

[image: windows update 8]

[image: windows update 9]

[image: windows update 10]

[image: windows update 11]

[image: windows update 12]

[image: windows update 13]

[image: windows update 14]

Note that none of this helped solve the problem.

It looks like I will have to reinstall Windows all over again. Till then I will just ignore and hide these stupid updates and disable Windows Update altogether. Stupid Microsoft...

Comment: I tried networked safe mode but Windows Update is not available in safe mode, I didn't know that. If I try to search for it (instant search from start menu) and click on it, it causes explorer to overload the cpu and I have to force close it and start it again. Windows Update is not even available from the Security Center in safe mode.

Comment: I also tried to download and run `MicrosoftFixit.wu.RNP.35273988777121892.2.1.Run.exe` which is the Fix It for Windows Update. It said it found some bad apples and it said it fixed it but I can still not install the updates in Windows Update.

Comment: One thing that could have messed things up, which it should not really, is that I have changed the display language in Windows from Swedish to English. But how can this mess up Windows Update?... aren't I supposed to be able to change the display language in Ultimate? So this was the only "major" change I did in the system before I started having problems.

Comment: I also did a system restore to a time before I did the change of display language. This didn't help. Then I tried using WinRE from the DVD and repair the computer but it found nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

In Safe mode navigate to your C:\Windows  folder, look for a folder called "SoftwareDistribution" right click on it and select rename, rename it to    SoftwareDistribution.old     hit enter.

Restart the PC and try Windows updates again.