# Windows Update error code 0x80240439 and web service xml errors

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm running Windows 10 Pro, Version 1511 (Build 10586.545). I wanted to install the Xbox Accessories App, but got the error code 0x80240439 without any further details. As it turns out, I get that error when I try to install any app (which definitely did work at some point before).

I tried to investigate and found this in the Windows Update logs (a few lines are in german, sorry, but the gist should be understandable):

```
2016.09.08 00:08:55.2999858 676   792   WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2016.09.08 00:08:55.6828367 676   792   WebServices     WS error: Fehler beim Vorverarbeiten der Eingabequelle durch den XML-Reader in Zeile 1, Spalte 1300 (0x514).
2016.09.08 00:08:55.6828370 676   792   WebServices     WS error: Ein Endelement wurde erwartet.
2016.09.08 00:08:55.6828373 676   792   WebServices     WS error: Ein unerwartetes Startelement mit dem Namen CacheLifetimeMinutes" und dem Namespace "http://www.microsoft.com/SoftwareDistribution/Server/ClientWebService" wurde gefunden."
2016.09.08 00:08:55.6828381 676   792   WebServices     Web service call failed with hr = 80240439.
2016.09.08 00:08:55.6828381 676   792   WebServices     Current service auth scheme=0.
2016.09.08 00:08:55.6828384 676   792   WebServices     Current Proxy auth scheme=0.
2016.09.08 00:08:55.6836675 676   792   SLS             Retrieving SLS response from server using ETAG UODGUpPpKUSECGXeqbwPMdg0BYySCWk9UJebGlbHGPI=_1440"..."
2016.09.08 00:08:55.6837677 676   792   SLS             Making request with URL HTTPS://sls.update.microsoft.com/SLS/{855E8A7C-ECB4-4CA3-B045-1DFA50104289}/x64/10.0.10586.0/0?CH=739&L=de-DE&P=&PT=0x30&WUA=10.0.10586.545
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6741275 676   792   Misc            StatusCode for transaction returned from WinHttpQueryHeaders is 304
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6766369 676   792   Misc            Got 855E8A7C-ECB4-4CA3-B045-1DFA50104289 redir Client/Server URL: https://fe3.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/ClientWebService/client.asmx""
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6777986 676   792   Misc            Token Requested with 0 category IDs.
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6927945 676   792   Misc            Acquired new token from Server
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6928651 676   792   Misc            Got service 855E8A7C-ECB4-4CA3-B045-1DFA50104289 plugin Client/Server auth token of type 0x00000001
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6932602 676   792   ProtocolTalker  PTError: 0x80240439
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6932613 676   792   ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates_WithRecovery failed. 0x80240439
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6932642 676   792   ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates round trips: 1
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6932644 676   792   ProtocolTalker  Sync of Updates 0x80240439
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6932667 676   792   ProtocolTalker  SyncServerUpdatesInternal failed 0x80240439
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6936103 676   792   Agent           Failed to synchronize, error = 0x80240439
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6962830 676   792   Agent           Exit code = 0x80240439
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6962835 676   792   Agent           * END * Finding updates CallerId = WSAcquisition  Id = 23
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6987966 6852  4772  ComApi          *RESUMED* Search ClientId = WSAcquisition
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6990560 6852  4772  ComApi          Updates found = 0
2016.09.08 00:08:56.6990563 6852  4772  ComApi          Exit code = 0x00000000, Result code = 0x80240439
```

The first few lines sound like the XML response from a web service is invalid. How could that happen? I doubt that the Microsoft servers are returning incorrect data, so it's probably something on my device?

Comment: First Step: Upgrade to Version 1607

Comment: I checked the Windows Update dialog, it says I have the newest version.
EDIT: I saw now that 1607 is the Anniversary Update, which has been out for a while. Maybe my Windows Update is generally broken?

Comment: You are running Version 1511, you are not running the current version 1607, use [Windows10Upgrade9252.exe](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799445) to upgrade to the current version.  Most problems like the one you have, are solved by in-place upgrades, the upgrade to Version 1607 would be considered an in-place upgrade.  You have severe Windows Update problems, so solve those, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: [Error codes 80070490 and 8024200D in Windows Update](http://superuser.com/questions/489358/error-codes-80070490-and-8024200d-in-windows-update?rq=1) follow the instructions in the answer here if the upgrade to Version 1607 doesn't help.

Comment: It works now after the manual update to version 1607, thanks!

Comment: You should submit your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound since you seem to have been the one with the solution, why not write it up and get credit?

Comment: @IanM it isn't my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my Windows Update was broken in some still unknown way, and didn't update to the most recent Windows version. As Ramhound suggested, I manually updated by running the executable from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799445, and then it worked.